# Facing Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.microsoftonline.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am calling microsoft Azureurl with restTemplate in springboot application
Url:-https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/v2.0/token

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("grant_type","client_credentials");
    map.add("client_id","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    map.add("client_secret","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    map.add("scope","https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response =
            restTemplate.exchange("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-c666dbeda42c\n/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    entity,
                    String.class);

    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        System.out.println("Request Successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Request Failed");
    }
```

While running  the above sample call to connect with Azure, we are getting the Exception as : Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.microsoftonline.com

Later tried at home, where there is no Proxy to connect to the internet, and then am able to successfully get output without this "UnknownHostException" error.
So how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your url seems to be not specification `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-c666dbeda42c\n/oauth2/v2.0/token`, try to change it to: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-c666dbeda42c/oauth2/v2.0/token` . Remove `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error for a **missing proxy configuration**. (I was googling for solutions for a specific case)
"Host not found" has nothing to do with the url parameters, but as said just before, having "\n" in an url is never a good idea.

Comment: I think it would be better to add this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("grant_type","client_credentials");
map.add("client_id","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
map.add("client_secret","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
map.add("scope","https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response =
        restTemplate.exchange("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-c666dbeda42c\n/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                entity,
                String.class);

if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
    System.out.println("Request Successful");
} else {
    System.out.println("Request Failed");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**